# Error : Loops in ajax methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have $.get methods like this :

```
$.get("/url" , function(z) {
   var a = $(z).find("span");
   for (var i = 0 ; i<a.length; i++){
      var v = $(a).eq(i).children("strong:first").text();
      alert(v);
   }
});
```

But screen doesn't print the result **v** so can you tell me what  problem is ?

Comment: z is integer value it's index value.

Comment: Why do you think it should alert it?

Comment: check a.length first if it is >0 then it will work and see your console is this any error come in response

Comment: @tushargupta index of what? Isn't it the response from the server?

Comment: z and v are poor names for your variable, doesn't tell anybody what it's for.

Comment: Please provide a simple example of the markup that the server would respond with.

Comment: well  if I use replace alert(v) with console.log(z); the result like this form : Number of that html's characters and the html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `.each()` in this case rather than defining a for loop

```
$.get("/url" , function(z) {
   var a = $(z).find("span");
   a.each(function(){
      var v = $(this).children("strong:first").text();
      alert(v);
   });
});
```

This assumes `z` the data from the get response is a valid DOM structure with children spans.

in order for an alert of `v` to be called `z` must look something like this

```
<div>
    <span>
        <strong>will alert</strong>
        <strong>will not alert</strong>
    </span>
    <span>
        <strong>will alert</strong>
        <strong>will not alert</strong>
    </span>
</div>
```

the `span`/`strong` structure must be like this in order for your selector to match since `.children()` only goes one element deep

Comment: What would it change? How your solution is supposed to solve the issue? And what is the actual issue?